# Angular, how to select an item from a list which is retrieved using ajax

Tags: ajax, angularjs, selection

So this is somewhat weird to me. Angular supports selects by reference however there is no support of selecting by value.

Here's my case and why I'm kind of puzzled:

I've got a form for editing a model. I fetch both the model, and a list of possible values for one of the models properties by ajax in a JSON format.

The model property contains a value, and that same value is in the list so before reading through the API I believed that ng-model binding will take care of selecting the right item for me, however I was wrong. AngularJS API for select states `Note: ngModel compares by reference, not value. This is important when binding to an array of objects.`

Now I'm in a dilemma as to how to do this. The "simplest" solution I figured is to iterate over the list(Which could contain up to 500+ items) and compare properties until I find the one I'm looking for. That would be extremely slow.

Here's a primitive example of what's going on: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cgNkGfpD2P6w4ECaXtdB?p=preview)

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon closer inspection of [AngularJS API for select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) I've noticed this `ngOptions` expression example: `select as label group by group for value in array track by trackexpr` and trying out numerous expressions I've found one that works for me. Since all of my objects have an id property I simply use `ng-options="item.text for item in items track by item.id"` and it works.

Sadly I haven't yet figured out a way to do the same with angular-ui-select2.

A complete example can be found here on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yQoAfeHppGle4eo7Yshg)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use ng-model on your select field and store the selected object in there? And then just set the value of your model to the selected object's field you are interested?

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options"></select>
// in controller
$scope.options = // $resource.get or whatever to fetch data
$scope.selected = $scope.options[0];
$scope.yourModel.valueYouWantToPersist = $scope.selected.valueYouWantToPersist;
```

You can put the placeholder element at the beginning of the options field before you fetch data, which would have some null value that would indicate to you thatuser didn't select anything, or you can just set $scope.selected as null, and it will still work fine. Because of data-binding, yourModel.valueYouWantToPersist will update as the $scope.selected updates, and you won't have to search the options field for a selected object.

It feels right to me, sorry if this answer doesn't work for you, I'm still a bit fresh with Angular and to be honest, not quite sure if I understood your problem to the fullest. Just try this solution with your code, and I think it should work.

Comment: That's all fine and well, but the issue is that the model already has a value, and I wish for the select to reflect that value(Clicking on edit i wish to see all current values of the model). However since the object in the list and the object in the model are not the same **reference** wise (but they are equal in **value** of all their properties) it is not automatically selected. The only solution I've come up with so far is to manually search each object in the list and compare property values which is too slow, especially if the list contains a lot of objects.

Comment: Oh and I forgot to mention, list items bind correctly to the model once I select them, that's not the issue. The issue is the initial select upon entering the view. The model property has it's own value and the fetched list contains the same value, **however** since they are different objects **reference** wise angular does not equate them and thus nothing is selected. I'll try to make up an example when I get home from work and post it in the OP.

Comment: Yeah I get what is the problem. Don't know better way to fix it. When I find out, I'll post it here, if someone else doesn't in the meantime.

Comment: I've figured it out and posted an answer. Thanks for the help.